# How to make each user run with its own credentials in my local Git?

Tags: git

I have a local git version control installed on RedHat 8 server.

When I run `git add *`, it asks me to provide the sudo permissions which is `sudo git add *`. This makes the add run with the root for me. All the other team members do the same.

When I run `git log` it provides me with the list of changes however the **changer** for all changes is **root**.

How to make each user run with its own credentials?

Comment: I think I answered this question over at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/753692/local-git-multi-users-issue already. You're trying to use git in a way that git was specifically designed **against**. So, please see my answer over at UNIX.SE.